# GCM.send exception at doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement gcm to my app.
I'm getting error at doInBackground at the gcm.send command, I've checked that the parameters are all fine with values.

The logCat:

```
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at com.example.catchme2.GoogleMapFragment$10.doInBackground(GoogleMapFragment.java:602)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at com.example.catchme2.GoogleMapFragment$10.doInBackground(GoogleMapFragment.java:1)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-02 17:01:52.313: E/AndroidRuntime(13881):    ... 5 more
```

and the code:

```
public void sendAmessage ()
    {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                        data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
                        data.putString("my_action",
                                "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
                        String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
                        gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
                        msg = "Sent message";
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                 if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.cancel();
                    }

                    MainActivity m = (MainActivity)getActivity();
                    m.LoadSetFrom();
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

I cant get into the catch statment since it's breaking up after the gcm.send line, and from the logcat it may seem that I'm dealing with asynctask issue.

Comment: gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that value assigned to `gcm` is not null? You should obtain GCM instance by calling `GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this)` inside the `onCreate()` method. If you need more detailed answer please post complete code of `GoogleMapFragment`

Comment: It's about 700 lines of code so I dont this it's possible... What do you mean by "value assigned to gcm is not null?", the sender_id value?

Comment: I mean gcm variable itself

Comment: Thanks, I've added this line: gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getActivity()); before gcm.send and it solved the crash issue. but I cant see the massege by now...